# Right click menu code will not run

Tags: python-2.7, contextmenu, pyside, qtreeview

I'm trying to create a menu that appears when I click the right mouse button, I've followed some tutorials, but when I put them in my code, and change them, they won't work.

This is my code:

```
def First(self):
    FirstFrame = QtGui.QFrame()
    FirstFrame.setFixedSize(230,660)
# LIST VIEW FOLDER
    self.folders_lv = QtGui.QTreeView()
    self.folders_lv.

# DEFINE THE FUNCTION FOR FIRST FRAME
    Firstbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    Firstbox.addWidget(self.folders_lv,3,0,1,4)
    Firstbox.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
    FirstFrame.setLayout(Firstbox)

    self.folders_lv.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
    self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu())

    return FirstFrame


def showMenu(self, pos):
    menu= QtGui.QMenu(self)
    menu.addAction(QtGui.QAction("Item 1", menu))
    menu.addAction(QtGui.QAction("Item 2", menu))
    menu.addAction(QtGui.QAction("Item 3", menu))
    menu.popup(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
```

Comment: So it was just a small typo (the showMenu())? IDEs can sometimes detect such mistakes. Also there should have been an error message telling you the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function *object* when connecting the signal, so get rid of the parentheses:

```
   self.folders_lv.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu)
```

Also, in the `showMenu` slot, you probably want:

```
   menu.popup(self.folders_lv.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))
```

Comment: I had follow your comment, but it still can not work, maybe i will you more about my code.

Comment: @MinhTuanNguyen. Sorry, there was a small error in the first line of my example code, which is now fixed.